# Minecraft Fullscreen not working

Tags: java, minecraft, fullscreen

I upgraded to Quantal recently, and Minecraft seems to not want to run in fullscreen. When I go to fullscreen it, the screen will go black for a second, as if it was about to go fullscreen normally, but then it just restores back into its window. So far I have tried:

- using different JREs (I've tried openjdk 6 and 7, as well as oracle7). Oracle's jre wouldn't even run Minecraft (I just got a black screen after logging in)
- switching graphics drivers (tried nvidia-current, nvidia-current-updates, and xserver-xorg-video-nouveau)
- updating minecraft bin files
- updating lwjgl libraries separately from the lwjgl site

None of this seemed to work at all.

I am running Minecraft with the command `java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -cp minecraft.jar net.minecraft.LauncherFrame`

Graphics card is GeForce 9500 GS/PCIe/SSE2.

Everything was working fine a few days ago when I was on 12.04.

Comment: I have opened bug in launchpad .Please help to contribute .Thanks [minecraft fullscreen problems ubuntu 12.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1079731)

Answer (score 3):

This happens to me too. But, at random, when I press F11, it goes full screen.
So I keep pressing F11 until it stays full screen.
Sometimes it takes up to 10 tries.

Try using [Magic Launcher](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/939149-launcher-magic-launcher-100-mods-options-news/)

Comment: For me it took like 30 tries